# Как можно сохранить список словарей в файл в CSV формате?

Tags: python, csv

Как можно сохранить словарь в файл в такой ситуации?

```
import csv
w = csv.writer(open("un.csv", "w"))
a = [
{"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "city": "Moscow"},
{"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "city": "Khabarovsk"},
{"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "city": "Sahalin"}
]
for key, val in a.items():
    w.writerow([key, val])
```

Comment: Сделайте его списком -- ключи словаря -- название столбцов, а значения словаря -- ячейки строки

Comment: А что мешает сделать вложенный список?

Answer (score 1):

Можно [воспользоваться `csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

people = [
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "city": "Moscow"},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "city": "Khabarovsk"},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "city": "Sahalin"}
]
with open('people.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=people[0])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(people)
```

#### people.csv

```
name,age,city
Tom,10,Moscow
Mark,5,Khabarovsk
Pam,7,Sahalin
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать таким образом:

```
import csv

data = [
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "city": "Moscow"},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "city": "Khabarovsk"},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "city": "Sahalin"}
]

with open("file.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    # write column names
    csv_writer.writerow(data[0].keys())
    # iterate over data dicts and write values
    for dict_item in data:
        csv_writer.writerow(dict_item.values())
```

Содержание файла `file.csv`:

```
city,age,name
Moscow,10,Tom
Khabarovsk,5,Mark
Sahalin,7,Pam
```